# Use terra::global to compute mode of each raster band

Tags: r, raster, terra

How might I use the `terra::global` function with a custom-made function? For example, I'd like to compute the mode of each band of a 14-band raster.

```
# say I have a 14-band raster called ras
# I make this function to compute the mode:

getmode <- function(v) {
  uniqv <- as.vector(unique(v))
  uniqv[!is.na(uniqv)]
  uniqv[which.max(tabulate(match(v, uniqv)))]
}
mode_all <- global(ras, getmode)
```

This code runs, but returns all `NA` values despite dropping NAs above. What am I missing here? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that on the last line of the function you are giving `match` a raster object `v`. The line to drop `NA` values also needs to be assigned back to `uniqv`.

```r
getmode <- function(in_raster) {
  v <- as.vector(in_raster)
  uniqv <- unique(r)
  uniqv <- uniqv[!is.na(uniqv)]
  uniqv[which.max(tabulate(match(v, uniqv)))]
}
```

---

Test on a raster

```
library(terra)
#> terra version 1.3.4
f <- system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra")
r <- rast(f)

global(r, getmode)
#>             global
#> elevation      319


# Test on stacked raster
s <- c(r, r)
global(s, getmode)
#>             global
#> elevation      319
#> elevation.1    319
```